# Yosemite: How can I diagnose problem where Chrome won't download anything

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google

When I try to download anything in chrome, nothing happens (eg. saving an image with right click). When I try to download an extension, chrome says `This item is already being downloaded and added into Chrome.` I looked "under the hood" and the Download folder is correctly set. Downloads work in safari. This problem also persists in Chromium. I have tried several solutions to my problem, but I simply cannot download anything. I tried deleting my chrome profile, pasting a past solution into terminal, as well as completely deleting all chrome applications I could find and reinstalling. I thought this could be a cache problem and deleted the cache (`sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches`) as well as my Google Library folder (`rm -rf ~/Library/Google`). However, none of these attempts have affected my situation

What could be causing this issue? How do I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my system software now everything works